# Can I use click through for file uploads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this some what outdated article by quirksmode it does not use the click through method because it was not supported by FireFox.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

However, I tested it and it works fine.  I can produce a click event on a file input.

Are there any other limitations I might not be aware of.  I basically want to use the method in the article, but use the more simple method of passing the click event from the fake input directly to the real input.

I've emailed the author and asked if he has any additional thoughts since Firefox now supports it.

I plan to implement it and will provide and info I find out.

Comment: Try and see? (And fail, ask a more specific question, try again, fail better?)

Comment: happy jack ... use the blocking div to capture click events and turn the display off on the actual input all together ... now you got some sand.